# How can I make a way to return error message of record not available?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch user cars, which is working fine. But I want to add if-statement which should return a error message `no record found`. I am trying as like below

```
$UserCars = User::with('cars')->findOrFail(request()->user()->id);
if ($UserCars !== null) {
    $Result = $UserCars->cars;
}else{
    $Result = response()->json(['data' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
}

return new CarResource($Result);
```

The problem is it is working when if-statement `true` (means when found record in database) but in case of false condition it returns html page with following message

`Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

`CarResource` is API resource which I am using for API's.

Can someone kindly guide me about this I would appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between the `find()` method and the `findOrFail()` one.

`findOrFail()` will trigger a `ModelNotFound` exception when no result is available. To change the output of this kind of exception (without doing a try catch() ) you need to intercept the exception in the `render()` method in `App\Exceptions\Handler::class`.
tell me if you want an example of this.

another very easy way is to simply do a find.

```
$UserCars = User::with('cars')->find(request()->user()->id);
//this will return either an instance of User or null
if ($UserCars) {
    $Result = $UserCars->cars;
    $response = new CarResource($Result);
}else{
    $response = response()->json(['data' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
}
return $response;
```

also since you are recovering the user for the `request()` helper, there is no need to request the user again from DB, just do it like this.

```
$user = $request->user();
if ($user) {
    $response = new CarResource($user->cars);
} else {
    $response = response()->json(['data' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
}

return $response;
```

Comment: For me this one is so good, but when I try to put static id `find(4);` just for verify functionality it return error

Comment: It is `Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::toBase does not exist.`

Comment: I just would like to request that I want to use return only once at the end. So let's do magic if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$UserCars = User::with('cars')->findOrFail(request()->user()->id);
if ($UserCars !== null) {
    $Result = $UserCars->cars;

    return new CarResource($Result);

}else{
    return response()->json(['data' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
}
```

Comment: Well I want to return at the end of the function. Anyways I tried your suggestions which are not working

Answer (score 0):

You already have the user, so you can just do the following:

```
// Get the cars from the user    
$cars = request()->user()->cars;
// Verify a filled collection was retrieved    
if ($cars->isNotEmpty()) {
    $result = CarResource::collection($cars);
} else {
    // No cars were found for the current user
    $result = response()->json(['data' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
}

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: `request()->user()` already should return Found user. This means that `User::with('cars')->findOrFail(request()->user()->id);` See still goes to query the db for the user then load related cars.

Secondly, `findOrFail()` would help you trigger 404 Error as a response so if the user is not found it will never hit this line `if ($UserCars !== null) {`

Thirdly, I believe CarResource should expect a **model** and not a `Response` object hence there might be something going wrong there.

Fourth, Is the route for this controller method declared in the *api* routes file? I asked then Laravel would handle the response as json for you when there's an error.

My proposal would be this:

```
$user = $request->user();

if ($user) {
    return new CarResource($user->load('cars'));
}

return response()->json(['data' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
```

> PS: I am not familiar with APIResources but I had an idea of doing so from [Fractal Transformer](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/).